# how to invite someone to go somewhere?

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to know how to invite someone to go somewhere (in German). For example, I want to invite my wife to go with me to the market, or to invite her to dinner with me.

PS. I am learning German by myself.

Comment: What is your specific question? Did you try a dictionary? Plain translation requests are off topic on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are a lot ways to express your desire!**
Also don't forget that expressing something also reflects your personalty.
(e.g. *You could just walk trough the city and bring her to the dinner without explaining that you want to invite her to a dinner...*)

But as you learn German I will make up some invitations:

**To wife**:
"`Lass mich dich zum essen einladen.`" : "*Let me invite you to dinner.*"
"`Wollen wir heute Abend essen gehen?`" : "*Do we want to go to the dinner tonight?*"
"`Möchtest du heute Abend mit mir essen gehen?`" : "*Do you want to go dining with me tonight?*"
"`Darf ich dich heute Abend einladen?`": "*May I invite you tonight?*"
...

You can also build a "standard":
"`Darf ich dich zum/ins/zur/.../auf [target] einladen?`" : "*May I invite you to/into [target]*"
*(Maybe there are also other prepositions apart from 'zum' and 'in' and the other ones)*
So now you try to find a german translation for your target and substitue "[target]" with that german word. You somehow have to figure out which preposition to use... but even if you did that wrong a german would still understand it.
(*If you know that your German isn't perfect, then this is a way to get your problem solved. Somehow...*)

**to mate**:
"`Lass uns einen heben!`" : "*Lets lift one/[lift a beer].*" as "*Lets go drinking.*"
"`Ne(Eine) Runde auf mich?`" : "*One Round on me?*" 
(**!You will say that you buy one beer/drink for everyone!**)
While we are in the pup we sometimes leave "Runde" and just say "`Die nächste geht auf mich!`". But mind that one could think you refer to a girl with saying "Die".
So make sure that the context is right ; )
Actually one can also order  beer with pointing on your beer and just say "Noch eins bitte.": "*One more please.*"
"`Ich gebe ein aus!`" : "*I'll buy a round*"
...

Comment: Warum sagt man eigentlich *"lass uns einen"*, und nicht *ein(s)*?

Comment: Weil es etwas extrem männliches ist, einen zu heben. ;-)

Comment: Du kannst  auch "ein" benutzen. Das hört sich IMHO aber nicht so schön an.  Vlt. ist meine Version sogar falsch. Wenn du aber "Lass uns eins heben." sagst, dann hört sich das für mich so an, als willst du exakt ein Bier/...  trinken. Und das will man ja meistens nicht :)

Comment: @Toscho das mag zwar stimmen, aber daher kommt es nicht... es kommt (hoffentlich) von *"einem Humpen"*

Answer (score 2):

Londane's answers pretty much got you covered on restaurants and bars.

When asking if your wife wants to go to the market you could say "Gehen wir auf den Markt?" or "Kommst Du mit auf den Markt?" The later implies that you'll go anyway and she can come too, but if she doesn't want to, you don't mind going alone.